# Regex requires too many steps

Tags: java, regex

Could you please correct my regex?

I need to match all `<img>` tags which have a `?contextId` inside of `src`. For instance the following string should be matched:

```
<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="http://10.3.34.34:8080/Bilder/pic.png?contextId=qualifier123" alt="Bild" />
```

I wrote the regular expression and it does what I need:

```
(?i)<img[^>]+? src\s*?=\s*?"(.*?\?contextId.*?)"[^\/]+?\/>
```

But it seems to me it takes too many steps (380 here) to parse: [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA6uY7/1)

Input string can be up to 30,000 characters and I worry that Java regex engine may fail with my non-optimized expression.

Comment: What is the desired return? Do you want the whole `img` tag? Just the `src`? Something else?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: Your regex is incorrect; the third example [here](https://regex101.com/r/iR2sQ0/1) is matched and should not be. Here's a  solution (that also takes less steps because I removed some lazy modifiers): https://regex101.com/r/bF8eI9/1. Anyway, I think you should follow Biffen's advice above.

Comment: I need the both whole `<img>` tag and link of `src`.

Comment: Biffen, thank you! Should I use jsoup for parcing?

Comment: Wolf, thank you! But the regex you sent in your link is the the same as mine. Could you please check it. May be it was not updated or saved?

Comment: @Aleks jsoup is one option, but there are others. Pick your favourite.

Comment: `<img.+?src.+\?contextId.+$` 98 steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

98 steps ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQ2dK4/1)):

```
<img.*?src="[^"]+\?contextId[^>]+>
```

This regex makes the assumption that the html is not malformed and particularly expects that each `img` tag has a `src` attribute.

EDIT: 104 steps to take both the `img` and the `src` link ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vO6pE5/1)):

```
(<img.*?src="([^"]+\?contextId[^"]+)"[^>]+>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your regex:

```
<img.*?src\s*=\s*"([^"]*\?contextId[^"]*)

1)   *? to [^"]*    # match non "(double quotes) characters instead of .(dot)
2)  "[^\/]+?\/>     # no need to match this part
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/qL2mM5/4)